# ng-repeat not working in a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following angular code

```
$scope.receipts = {
    acquirer : [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "test",
            balanceAmount: 4462.29,
            cardProducts: [
                {
                    cardProduct: {
                        balanceAmount: 2222,
                        id: 1,
                        name: "MASTERCARD CREDITO",
                        lancamentos: [
                            {
                                description: "vendas",
                                payedAmount: 1111
                            },
                            {
                                description: "cancelamentos",
                                payedAmount: 1111
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I am trying use ng-repeat to make an table

```
<tbody ng-repeat="i in receipts.acquirer[0].cardProducts[0].cardProduct">
   <tr>
      <th>
         <div class="cardFlag brand_1"></div>
         {{ i.name }}
      </th>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

but it's not showing the name "MASTERCARD CRÉDITO".
What is wrong in my code ? 
Am I using ng-repeat in a wrong way ?

Comment: Yep, you are doing it wrong. Because cardProduct is not array, you can't ng-repeat it. Just write it without ng-repeat, leave repeat for collections, not objects.

Comment: @vedmaque yes you can. You just can't use the standard array syntax.

Comment: @vedmaque, ng-repeat can repeat over an array or the properties of an object, [see the documentation on ngRepeat directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties)

Comment: Yep, yep, my bad. Completely forgot

Answer (score 0):

If you need the output to be 'test', you have to change the ng-repeat to this :

```js
ng-repeat="i in receipts[0].acquirer"
```

The code you have currently, refers to the name of the 'cardProduct' object : MASTERCARD CREDITO

Comment: sorry. I mistyped.. I need the output mastercard credito.

Comment: Then it's like  
@vedmaque said. You have to use ng-repeat over an array. That's why your answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is ng-repeat is repeating over the object's properties and the values of those properties is going into `i`. `i` is not the object. So it would just be `i` and not `i.name` or `i.balandAmount`.

You can also change the ng-repeat expression to be `(key,value) in`. This will put the property name in `key` and the property value in `value`

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in receipts.acquirer[0].cardProducts[0].cardProduct"
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.receipts = {
      acquirer : [
          {
              id: 1,
              name: "test",
              balanceAmount: 4462.29,
              cardProducts: [
                  {
                      cardProduct: {
                          balanceAmount: 2222,
                          id: 1,
                          name: "MASTERCARD CREDITO",
                          lancamentos: [
                              {
                                  description: "vendas",
                                  payedAmount: 1111
                              },
                              {
                                  description: "cancelamentos",
                                  payedAmount: 1111
                              }
                          ]
                      }
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in receipts.acquirer[0].cardProducts[0].cardProduct">
      <th>
        <div class="cardFlag brand_1"></div>
        {{ key }}
      </th>
      <td>
        {{value}}
      </td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you had meant to repeat over each item in the `cardProducts` array just end the expression with `.cardProducts`

```
ng-repeat="i in receipts.acquirer[0].cardProducts"
```

And then use `i.cardProduct` to access the object, ie `i.cardProduct.name`

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.receipts = {
      acquirer : [
          {
              id: 1,
              name: "test",
              balanceAmount: 4462.29,
              cardProducts: [
                  {
                      cardProduct: {
                          balanceAmount: 2222,
                          id: 1,
                          name: "MASTERCARD CREDITO",
                          lancamentos: [
                              {
                                  description: "vendas",
                                  payedAmount: 1111
                              },
                              {
                                  description: "cancelamentos",
                                  payedAmount: 1111
                              }
                          ]
                      }
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in receipts.acquirer[0].cardProducts">
      <th>
        <div class="cardFlag brand_1"></div>
        {{ i.cardProduct.name }}
      </th>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but i changed my ng-repeat to

```
<tbody ng-repeat="i in receipts.acquirer[0].cardProducts[0]">
```

and it worked.
Is there a logical answer to this ?